# Close popover - Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipopovercontroller

Good Day,

I'm having a problem to close a popover after selecting a line (UITableView). I've tried the following methods, but were unsuccessful.

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

iMAPClientesPesquisar *a = [[iMAPClientesPesquisar alloc] init];
    [a.popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

I'm calling my popover as follows:

```
- (IBAction)Filtro:(id)sender {

    iMAPClientesFiltro *ClientesFiltro = [[iMAPClientesFiltro alloc] init];
    popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:ClientesFiltro];
    [ClientesFiltro release];
    [popover setPopoverContentSize:CGSizeMake(132, 132)];
    [popover presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
}
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let me explain:

I have two classes, one containing the button that will trigger the popover and one which is properly the popover (which in reality it is a UIView). When I select a line of UITableView in this UIView want this visualization is complete. So I tried to use the first method described above.

Comment: Did you get everything worked out?

Comment: Yes, I managed to solve my problem in the following forum: http://bit.ly/vi0Uvt. I thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to close the popover from the same view controller that the Filtro method is in (or in other words, popover would be an variable visible from within that class), you should be able to drop the "a." from your above line and just do:

```
[popover dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to dismiss the popover is to have a reference to the popover that is open.  I'm a little confused why you are calling `[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` as that has nothing to do with a UIPopoverController.

You need to use the original popover reference to dismiss the popover.  Something like `[popover dimissPopoverAnimated:YES];` since `popover` appears to be a member variable of the object that had the function that originally opened the popover.